# Same div updated by 2 Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a div which holds a table.
This table supports pagingation via [PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/) in an ajax fashion.

Code:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("NavigateToPage", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                {"pageNumber", page},
            }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "toUpdate"}))
```

Also, I want the table to be refreshed every 30 seconds. So I wrote jQuery like this to update every 30 seconds,

```
var ajaxUpdateFunction = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "/Home/NavigateToPage",
        data: {
            pageNumber:$(".active").text()                
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#toUpdate').replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        },
    });
 };
  $(function() {
     setInterval(function () {
        ajaxUpdateFunction();
    }, 10000);  
});
```

But, when the jQuery ajax update starts working, the pagedList navigation is not working. If I comment the jQuery ajax function, the pagedList navigation is working.

What is going wrong here? Shouldn't I update the same div by 2 different ajax calls?

Will I be able to do table refresh in Razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you  need is [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#toUpdate').html(data);
},
```

the `replaceWith()` function removes the element from `DOM`, So after your code runs, the plugin will not be able to access it since it does not exist anymore...

Comment: @Twilwin: Thanks a lot, You are right. Very sad that I am able to press up button only once :-(

Comment: @Rockstart glad it helped. you can accept the answer instead :D

Comment: @Twilwin: I was not able to accept the answer in the first 5 minutes(StackOverFlow restriction)